# Filtering and returning parent object using lodash chain

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I want to use Lodash chain function to filter through an arrays nested array items and then return the full parent object.

Here is some dummy data from my use case to illustrate my issue:

```
const capital = [
  {
    "financeCategory": "Loans",
    "financeCategoryId": "22HM6fFFwx9eK2P42Onc",
    "financeElements": [
      {
        "financeCategoryId": "22HM6fFFwx9eK2P42Onc",
        "financeElementId": "JQiqqvGEugVQuI0fN1xQ",
        "financeElementTitle": "Convertible loan",
        "data": [
          {
            "month": 1,
            "value": 100,
            "year": "2020"
          },
          {
            "month": 1,
            "value": 100,
            "year": "2019"
          },
        ],

      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "financeCategory": "Investments",
    "financeCategoryId": "JtnUsk5M4oklIFk6cAlL",
    "financeElements": [] 
  },
  {
    "financeCategory": "Ownerships Contribution",
    "financeCategoryId": "PaDhGBm5uF0PhKJ1l6WX",
    "financeElements": []
  }
];
```

I want to filter on the "data" array within the financeElements and then return full expense object with the filter applied on "data".

Let's say I want to manipulate the expense object and only get the data on the financeElements that have the year 2020. I've tried like so:

```
const expenseFiltered: any = _.chain(expenses)
.flatMap('financeElements')
.flatMap('data')
.filter({year: '2020' as any}).value();
```

But that just gives me the filtered "data" objects. 
Output:

```
[{
            "month": 1,
            "value": 100,
            "year": "2020"
}]
```

Now I know there are ways that I could use that to produce the full object with the filtered data, but I really want to do this in just one simple _.chain command

Desired output

```
[
  {
    "financeCategory": "Loans",
    "financeCategoryId": "22HM6fFFwx9eK2P42Onc",
    "financeElements": [
      {
        "financeCategoryId": "22HM6fFFwx9eK2P42Onc",
        "financeElementId": "JQiqqvGEugVQuI0fN1xQ",
        "financeElementTitle": "Convertible loan",
        "data": [
          {
            "month": 1,
            "value": 100,
            "year": "2020"
          }
        ],

      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "financeCategory": "Investments",
    "financeCategoryId": "JtnUsk5M4oklIFk6cAlL",
    "financeElements": [] 
  },
  {
    "financeCategory": "Ownerships Contribution",
    "financeCategoryId": "PaDhGBm5uF0PhKJ1l6WX",
    "financeElements": []
  }
]
```

Is this possible using lodash chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A chain is used to transform a structure in several steps. In your case, you don't want to change the structure. You can use nested `Array.map()` (or lodash's `_.map()`) calls to iterate and rebuild the structure, and internally `_.filter()` the data:

```js
const capital = [{"financeCategory":"Loans","financeCategoryId":"22HM6fFFwx9eK2P42Onc","financeElements":[{"financeCategoryId":"22HM6fFFwx9eK2P42Onc","financeElementId":"JQiqqvGEugVQuI0fN1xQ","financeElementTitle":"Convertible loan","data":[{"month":1,"value":100,"year":"2020"},{"month":1,"value":100,"year":"2019"}]}]},{"financeCategory":"Investments","financeCategoryId":"JtnUsk5M4oklIFk6cAlL","financeElements":[]},{"financeCategory":"Ownerships Contribution","financeCategoryId":"PaDhGBm5uF0PhKJ1l6WX","financeElements":[]}];

const expenseFiltered = capital.map(ex => ({
  ...ex,
  financeElements: ex.financeElements.map(fe => ({
    ...fe,
    data: _.filter(fe.data, { year: '2020' })
  }))
}));

console.log(expenseFiltered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense, and will have to do then!
Was just trying something along with: 
_.chain(capital)
.values()
.filter({financeElements: [{data: [{ year: '2020' }]}] as any}).value();
But yeaah, just filters the financeElements and not data.
Thanks!